# Photoshop Shape to SVG file that I can stretch with background-size

Tags: html, css, image, svg

My goal is to have a pseudo element with a background image that stretches to the size of the element.

However, I can't get the SVG to stretch! I'm exporting it from PSD by selecting the shape and then File -> Export -> Export As... and then choose SVG.

Then when I try something like this:

```
.bg-blue-curved-top:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url('../img/product/curve.svg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

The SVG image (40x40 px) always keeps its aspect ratio of 1:1 and I can't stretch it.

I also tried including the SVG as an image element and scaled it. It still preserves the aspect ratio no matter what I do.

So how should I export a shape from photoshop to be able to stretch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the SVG file with a text editor
2. Change the "preserveAspectRatio" attribute of the `<svg>` tag to "none".